# Can we say anything about the set of all points of discontinuities of $f^{(1)}$,the derivative of a differentiable function on $\mathbb R$.

Tags: general-topology, derivatives, baire-category, continuity

We all know that for a differentiable function $f$ on $\mathbb R$,its derivative function can have only essential or $2$nd kind discontinuity.Now my question is if $X$ be that set of all points of discontinuities of the derivative function,then can we predict the nature of $X$,i.e.can we say anything about the structure of $X\subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: The set of discontinuities is a dense $F_{\sigma}$ set. I don't kn ow if every dense $F_{\sigma}$ set arises this way.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Woulf you explain elaborately?

Comment: The set of discontinuity points of any function is an $F_{\sigma}$. Now $f'(x)=\lim \frac {f(x+\frac  1n)-f(x)} {\frac  1n}$ and the point-wise  limit of any sequnce of continuous functions is continuous on  a dense set. This can be  proved using Baire Category Theorem.